# Add quotes to array keys in string

Tags: php, arrays, quotes

I have lot of code that has arrays like `$test[keyhere]`. Is there any way (in text editor for example) that could automatic correct this like `$test['keyhere']`.

**Example:**

```
echo "This is test variable: $test[keyhere] and...";
```

to this:

```
echo "This is test variable: ".$test['keyhere']." and...";
```

Comment: Almost every editor has `find and replace` with regexp

Comment: I will suggest use sublime text editor. where you can select multiple values at a same time and you can also edit at multiple lines at a same time.

Answer (score 1):

In notepad++ you could do this:

```
Find: (\$\w+)\[([a-zA-Z]\w+)\]
Replace: $1['$2']
```

The regex looks for something of the form `$identifier[chars]` where `chars` don't include surrounding quotes but also start with a letter (to avoid quoting numbers), and then replaces that with `$identifier['chars']`.

If you want to add the quotes and PHP concatenation operators, change the replace string to `".$1['$2']."`

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with PHP [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.array-map.php) :

```
<?php
    function addQuotes($n)
    {
        return "'" . $n . "'";
    }

    $a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    $b = array_map("addQuotes", $a);
    print_r($b);
?>
```

Or when you print just add quotes:

```
echo "This is test variable: '".$test['keyhere']."' and...";
```

In Editors you can use Find And Replace (almost every text editor has this option) usually shortkey is `cntrl + f` for find and there is an option for replace, `cntrl + shift + f` is also an option for shortkey.